# Brian Daley and James Luceno's collaboration as Jack McKinney

Tags: jack-mckinney

What is known about [Brian Daley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Daley) and [James Luceno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Luceno)'s manner of collaboration when they wrote as [Jack McKinney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_McKinney_%28writer%29)? (As in: did they tend to split up the book in the middle, or write a sentence each, or was one more of a plotter and the other more of a sentence smith, …)

The trigger for this question is that I've just read [*Kaduna Memories*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5130), I have the [*Black Hole Travel Agency* series](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?5600) in my pipeline, and I'm wondering what to expect from that, as well as what to expect from their works as sole authors (Robotech is not in my plans). So if you have reason to think that some aspect of *Kaduna Memories* is typical of Daley, Luceno or McKinney writing, I'm interested as well. (But let's please keep arguments about whether the books are good or not out of this.)

Comment: If you have value judgements about the books you'd like to share, [chat is a fine place](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/science-fiction-fantasy).

Answer (score 2):

I have read, but can't recall where, that for Robotech, they jointly time-lined the book, each wrote adjacent chapters from the timeline, traded and edited the other's chapter, traded back, then moved onto the next pair of chapters. Since, typically, the Robotech novels alternate between several parallel event locations on a chapter by chapter basis, this is actually much smoother than it otherwise might be.

I've not read any other works by either besides the Robotech series.

Comment: [The Wikipedia article for Robotech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotech_%28novels%29) seems to state they did this for books, not chapters, but only because they were under a tight deadline.